# App building: cordova-plugin-qrscanner does not allow Phonegap build

Tags: cordova, qr-code, phonegap

I am trying to develop a new app via Phonegap which includes the "cordova-plugin-qrscanner" plugin. In the config.xml I have the following;

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-qrscanner" spec="^2.6.0" source="npm" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
<preference name="pgb-builder-version" value="2" />
```

However, when building in Phonegap I receive the following error: *Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: QRScanner.java*

I can't seem to find any solutions available yet, and 2.6.0 appears to be the latest version available